# error with authorization header angular http

Tags: angular, typescript, https, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

i have backend  in node js expree and sequelize  im trying to get all my product_types when y made the peticion with postman to my backend this is the answer:

[postman http request and header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5AwQ.png)

but when i make the same peticion on my frontend angular i got a error

```
header Authorization is missing
```

this is my angular services http request

```js
 getTypes(token:any):Observable<any>{
    let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
                                   .set('Authorization', token);
    console.log(headers)
    return this._http.post(this.url + 'productType/getall', {headers:headers});
    
  }
```

this is the header that goes to my postman backend

```js
{
  authorization: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJkYXRhIjp7InN1YiI6MSwibmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwic3VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwicm9sZSI6InVzZXJfYWRtaW4iLCJpYXQiOjE2MzU2ODA3ODZ9LCJpYXQiOjE2MzU2ODA3ODYsImV4cCI6MTYzNTc2NzE4Nn0.9e-sP6ZnUeYe0EEpuLyQmxvIu7-U1_oXLZlt76XbBs0',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.28.3',
  accept: '*/*',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  'postman-token': 'b97c28a2-f88e-4953-93d5-199fd1443d77',
  host: 'localhost:3002',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '0'
}
```

and this one is from my angular frontend

```js
{                                                                                                                       
  host: 'localhost:3002',                                                                                               
  connection: 'keep-alive',                                                                                             
  'content-length': '476',                                                                                              
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="95", "Chromium";v="95", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',                                      
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',                                                                          
  'content-type': 'application/json',                                                                                   
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',                                                                                             
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95
.0.4638.54 Mobile Safari/537.36',                                                                                       
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',                                                                                    
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',                                                                                      
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',                                                                                        
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',                                                                                             
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',                                                                                            
  referer: 'http://localhost:4200/',                                                                                    
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',                                                                               
  'accept-language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8'                                                                          
}
```

i dont know why isnt sending the authorization with the token
the token isn't null

[angular consol with the token and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFPaF.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HttpClient `post` params are not in the correct order..

```
post(url: string, body: any, options: { headers?: HttpHeaders....
```

The 2nd param is the body of the `post`, 3rd is the options with headers

Or, maybe you should be using `get` - in which case you'd keep your params as is